# Complete system freeze

Tags: system, drivers, pantheon, hardware

My computer freezes completely every now and then.
I do nothing heavy on resources, plain browsing the internet reading articles.

When system freezes there is NOTHING I can do. Mouse not moving, I cannot call a virtual console, NOTHING.

Only solution is the hardware reset button.

My configuration is 
120 gb ssd
gigabyte A320M-s2h
amd ryzen 3 2200 g (radeon vega 8 mobile grfx)
8gb memory

Comment: Do you have logs, maybe /var/log/syslog, dmesg etc next time it occurs. Alternatively, `journalctl -o short-precise -k -b -1` for last boot info.

Comment: Oh ok will post as soon as it happens thank you for your help.

Comment: @trishmapow I have the output at hand, but it is too long a text to post here... Please advise?

Comment: try uploading it to somewhere like https://pastebin.com/ @George

Comment: @trishmapow  (posting two outputs after two events )
https://pastebin.com/raw/Vg5xjvPa 
https://pastebin.com/raw/3YGzU8tY

Comment: THIS IS GETTING FRUSTRATING...Numerous updates still no fix.